# Adding a new app with Fabric from a Xcode project with multiple targets

Tags: xcode8, google-fabric, fabric.io

I am trying to add multiple apps to Fabric, from a Xcode project with multiple targets. It wont work.

I have added a run script in BUILD PHASES for every target.
When I am in the 'new app boarding' process while using the Fabric Mac App, I will not come past the 'Install the SDK Kits'. In the project the Fabric SDK Kits are already added.... And adding the SDK Kits to all the specific targets also does not work.

If I run the specific targets, I DO see a changing name of the original (first added to Fabric) app to the newly to be added target. I also DO see a changed bundle ID. But I just DONT see a new app added to the FAbric Mac App and also not to the Fabric Dashboard.

Does anybody has any extra recommendations for adding multiple target apps from one Xcode project? Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like you're close. As long as you have the run script for all targets and then build and run each target, it should get added. Are you able to share your bundle IDs or your account info? I can take a closer look.

Update: Additionally, make sure that you're network is able to connect to our servers and that you allow HTTP Services in your simulator: Settings > Developer > Allow HTTP Services (turn on).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Bc of you noting I was close, I just keep persisting. Now I did come further in the process. I now get to the message 'Hmmm, seems like your kit isn't activating. If you're using the simulator, restart it and run your app again.'

Comment: And in the console I am getting the following: [Fabric] unable to complete application configure: Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=422, type=2, request_id=1be6eaccd3f00c0f333e8cfbbab95f2e, content_type=text/html; charset=utf-8}

Comment: I have clicked 'Read more' and followed the instructions; Restart the sim, etc. But still it doesnt work. Do you have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: Can I sent you my account info directly, through some kind of DM? Mail to support?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a network issue. Are you connecting through a proxy or behind a firewall? If you send an email to support@fabric.io with your bundle IDs we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: I am not connecting through a proxy or behind a firewall. But your answer triggered me to look at the network issue and it seems to have been caused by me changing wireless networks (also referred to in the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654679/cant-use-http-in-ios-8-simulator?noredirect=1&lq=1). So I just connected through ethernet and now it did work! I also had to do this in the simulator: Settings > Developer > Allow HTTP Services (turn on). Thanks!

Comment: @codeDude, glad to here it's working! Settings > Developer > Allow HTTP Services (turn on) was likely the key here. I've updated my answer to include this.