# iOS 9 simulator not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, xcode7

I downloaded Xcode 7 on my mac but it seems the iOS 9 simulator does not have internet connection,
I tried "Reset Content and Settings" and I restarted the simulator and Xcode but it doesn't seem to work,

Any solutions ?
Thank you

Comment: There are several other steps you can take. e.g. [turning of anti-virus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120795/xcode-6-beta-ios-8-simulator-cant-access-internet), [clearing proxy settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542706/iphone-simulator-cannot-connect-to-internet), turning off little snitch… Some people have luck removing & readding the network connection in network preferences. Some get it working by plugging in an ethernet cable, some get it working by turning on & off wifi…

Comment: Alexy what do u mean Simulator not working? for instance if u try to run an app in Debug mode what happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try adding this to your info.plist file

[image]

heres a link to the Apple Dev forum on the issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked your debugger?

> Are you getting Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP
>   (http://)

If so look at your info.plist and set your NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES. If you don't have they key add this to your plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: I was also bitten by this. In my opinion, it was a bit heavy-handed for Apple to make this change. Not all applications want or need SSL (especially in a development environment).

Comment: @Richard, no worries.

Comment: @Greg I was too.  I'm pretty sure most people will be