# iOS simulator no internet access

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7, internet-connection

I'm maintaining an iOS app that's a few targets behind, and when I run the simulator for the code, it launches the app succesfully, but when I attempt to login, the simulator reports it can't get access to wifi.

I was able to get the simulator working when I was using an older version of xcode, but I've recently updated osx to El Capiton, so I can't use that xcode anymore.
 - I've tried Revert content and settings on the simulator
 - I'm not behind a proxy.
 - This did work before when I was using older xcode version
 - current xcode version: 7.1
 - application Deployment target: 7.0

I've been on SO for a little while now, nothing I can find works, I've been through the first page of Google, and I'm not sure what else to do except try to downgrade my mac pro just so i can use old xcode again. Help?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to update to Xcode 7.1.

Comment: I'm now up to 7.1, and it makes no difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone simulator cannot connect to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542706/iphone-simulator-cannot-connect-to-internet)

Answer (score 7):

My pc had access to the internet, but the simulator could not open a website in Safari.

**What solved it for me was simply turning off and on the wifi**

Answer (score 2):

This works for me...

[Stack Overflow - "iPhone simulator cannot connect to internet
"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25993357)

> 1.Turn off lan connection; 
>   2.Turn on wifi; 
>   3.Settings > Developer > Allow HTTP Services (turn on); 
>   4.Restart Xcode and simulator.

[image]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @MukulKant I did it above the image

Answer (score 1):

With the simulator opened try to:

Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

Comment: That's one of the things I've tried before I posted.

Answer (score -2):

With the simulator opened try to:

Device> Restart

Comment: Restart Mac fixed my problem :(