# Xcode simulator network connection problem

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I build the application successfully using Xcode,
The application on the simulator cannot connect to the network "Don't have internet access",
Even that the browser inside the simulator can connect and have internet access.

I've tried
[iOS simulator no internet access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304970/ios-simulator-no-internet-access/48411608)
[iPhone simulator cannot connect to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542706/iphone-simulator-cannot-connect-to-internet)
And nothing seems to work for me.

Any help please?

macOS Big Sur Version 11.2.3

Xcode Version 12.5 (961.1)
SimulatorKit 609
CoreSimulator 757.5

I'm using React Native v0.64
Fetch API response is `[Error: Network Error]`

Logs

```
 [javascript] 'ApiClient', 'GET', '/api/v1/explores/image_feed'
    [Adjust]w: SANDBOX: Adjust is running in Sandbox mode. Use this setting for testing. Don't forget to set the environment to `production` before publishing
    [Adjust]d: Delegate implements adjustDeeplinkResponse:
    [Adjust]e: Adjust already initialized
    [Adjust]v: Foreground timer is already started
    [Adjust]v: Subsession start
    [Adjust]v: Started subsession 2 of session 1
    [Adjust]d: Wrote Activity state: ec:0 sc:1 ssc:2 ask:0 sl:62.2 ts:59.9 la:1621426622.1 dt:(null) gdprf:0 dtps:0 att:0
 [javascript] Default values set.
 [javascript] 'deeplink handling event', { url: null }
 7.11.0 - [Firebase/RemoteConfig][I-RCN000026] RCN Fetch failure. Response http error code: 403
 [javascript] [CodePush] App is up to date.
 [javascript] Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
Error: [remoteConfig/unknown] Internal Error. Status code: 403
NativeFirebaseError: [remoteConfig/unknown] Internal Error. Status code: 403
 [javascript] 'ApiClient', 'GET', '/api/v1/link_groups'
 [javascript] 'Be aware that changing the visibility of header in modal on iOS will result in resetting the state of the screen.', '\n    at NativeStackView 
 screen parameters are unexpected: MGScreenClass1125x2436x3x495 SCREEN_TYPE(1125,2436,3,495)
 [javascript] 'ApiClient', 'POST', '/api/v1/users/sign_in'
    [Adjust]v: Foreground timer fired
    [Adjust]d: Wrote Activity state: ec:0 sc:1 ssc:2 ask:0 sl:120.8 ts:118.5 la:1621426680.7 dt:(null) gdprf:0 dtps:0 att:0
    [Adjust]v: Foreground timer fired
    [Adjust]d: Wrote Activity state: ec:0 sc:1 ssc:2 ask:0 sl:180.8 ts:178.6 la:1621426740.7 dt:(null) gdprf:0 dtps:0 att:0
 [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C24.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]
 [connection] nw_read_request_report [C24] Receive failed with error "Connection reset by peer"
    [Adjust]v: Foreground timer fired
    [Adjust]d: Wrote Activity state: ec:0 sc:1 ssc:2 ask:0 sl:240.6 ts:238.3 la:1621426800.5 dt:(null) gdprf:0 dtps:0 att:0
```

Comment: Show us the error you're getting on your app.

Comment: I've added the logs I'm getting

Comment: I see `403` errors which means you are sending a bad request, but that's for Firebase. You'll have to find a way to explore `[Error: Network Error]` to know exactly what it is, because Network Errors come in many different flavors.