# XCode simulator: how to make Internet work for apps?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, nativescript

I am developing a NativeScript app (i.e. a native app compiled from web languages) and deploying it to XCode (7.2) emulator.

NativeScript uses the Xcode command line tools internally.

I am working under OS X 10.11 (El Captain) and I tried to deploy my app to iPhone 5 and iPhone6 emulators.

The issue I'm getting is that **my app can't reach REST APIs** (get/post/....).
I'm deploying my APIs using **json-server**.

On Linux with json-server + run to Android emulator it works perfectly so I'm pretty sure **it doesn't depend on json-server or my app code**.

I tried an old solution posted at: [iPhone simulator cannot connect to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542706/iphone-simulator-cannot-connect-to-internet)

Specifically, I've reset simulator settings as well as enabling 'HTTP services' in settings. **The issue is still there**. Any clue?

Comment: More importantly, which iOS version are you working on? Don't tell me you forgot to add network exceptions for iOS 9...

Comment: @Raptor as I said I'm pretty new to iOS development. Target version is 8 to support cocoapods, running version in Simulator is 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9) out. I might have something to do with Apple's Application Transport Security jargon.

Comment: thanks. I'll try asap and then I'll accept the answer. even though it will be a pain... since I need to override plist settings as I'm using nativescript which compiles to native but still is to an upper abstraction level

Comment: Did you give this a shot?

Comment: I will do it today or tomorrow at the latest (focusing on Android now). the question tab is there ready to be accepted (but I bet it will work if I manage to override plist settings ) :)