# React native http request

Tags: react-native

I use image, like this:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http://exmple.url/image.png'}}
       style={{
           width:  60 ,
           height:  60 ,
       }}
       resizeMode={"contain"} />
```

Image is not shown. But if I paste any HTTPS URL Image is shown. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable arbitrary load in info.plist of your ios project. By default ios don't allow http requests. See my earlier similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862837/react-native-ios-network-request-failed/38864329#38864329)

Comment: Thanks. I added in info.plist
`<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/> `
But not work. Maybe need rebuild project? But how it make?

Comment: Sorry, but... not work

I build project in xcode _Product => Build_
And _build and run_ .

In xcode i see NSAllowsArbitraryLoads with value _true_

Comment: @Wheelie can you try to render the image at the root of the app and see if that works? ( with NSAllows.. thing set to true, of course.)