# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection with async / await

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, async-await

In a ReactNative component, when I press a button I got the "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection" error when I execute this function:

```
async onAdd(item) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                event_id: item.id,
                event_type: item.event_type,
            })
        });
        const responseJson = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        error(error);
    }
}
```

I do not know why since its in a try / catch block.

**UPDATED**
This is the error function:

```
function error(value) {
    if (console) {
        console.error(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well `error(error)` is most likely throwing an exception, as `error` is not a function.

Comment: What is your 'error()' method doing?  If it throws an error, so will onAdd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842499/react-native-possible-unhandled-promise-rejection

Comment: Is your code supposed to do something with `responseJson`?  Like return it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are redefining the symbol `error` here with the `catch` argument:

```
} catch (error) {
    error(error);
}
```

so that hides your `error()` function.  Change to this (with different names for the two symbols):

```
} catch (err) {
    error(err);
}
```

So, when you try to call `error(error)` you're trying to execute a non-function which throws which causes `onAdd()` to reject the promise that the async function returns and you don't have a `.catch()` handler on that function call (because you didn't think it could reject).  And, as long as your `catch()` handler is written so that it doesn't throw itself, then your promise won't reject, but your coding error was causing it to throw.

Answer (score -1):

The method that calls this function should handle the error too, probably on your React Class

Comment: I call the function on onpress attribute, onPress={() => this.onAdd(item)}