# while trying to insert the image in firebase storage [Error: [storage/unknown] The server has terminated the upload session]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Hey this is shubham and i am trying to create an authentication system using react native , firebase storage and firestore with an image picker by this user can upload his post but it's throwing some unusual error that is:

[Error: [storage/unknown] The server has terminated the upload session]
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)

and i am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66bbjSwJXjo&list=PL0X_59ppP62OzwSAgW0lBNA0v3Kauowg5

github repo: https://github.com/Sakshamz4554/reactnativeblog

and this is my Register.js file

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import {launchCamera, launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';

import {globalStyles} from '../../utils/globalStyles';

export default function Register() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [displayPicture, setDisplayPicture] = useState();

  function onPickPicture() {
    launchImageLibrary(
      {
        mediaType: 'photo',
      },
      data => setDisplayPicture(data.assets[0].uri),
    );
  }
  function onClickPicture() {
    launchCamera(
      {
        mediaType: 'photo',
      },
      data => setDisplayPicture(data.assets[0].uri),
    );
  }

  async function onRegister() {
    if (!email && !password) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      const {
        user: {uid},
      } = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

      let downloadURL = null;
      if (displayPicture) {
        const spiltPath = displayPicture.split('/');
        const imageName = spiltPath[spiltPath.length - 1];
        const reference = storage().ref(`${uid}/images/${imageName}`);
        const data = await reference.putFile(displayPicture);
        downloadURL = await storage()
          .ref(data.metadata.fullPath)
          .getDownloadURL();
      }

      firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .set({
          email,
          name,
          displayPicture: downloadURL,
        })
        .then(() => console.log('Done'));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={{uri: !displayPicture ? null : displayPicture}}
        style={styles.displayPicture}
      />
      <View style={styles.touchableContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPickPicture}>
          <Text>Pick Picture</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClickPicture}>
          <Text>Click Picture</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <TextInput
        value={name}
        placeholder="Name"
        style={globalStyles.primaryInput}
        onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
      />

      <TextInput
        value={email}
        placeholder="Email"
        style={globalStyles.primaryInput}
        onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
      />

      <TextInput
        value={password}
        placeholder="Password"
        style={globalStyles.primaryInput}
        onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
      />

      <Button title="Register" onPress={onRegister} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 1,
  },
  touchableContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '50%',
  },
  displayPicture: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  },
});
```

Comment: You may try handling the catch block in the way shown in the [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469708/possible-unhandled-promise-rejection-with-async-await). Let me know if that helps!

Comment: No i am still facing the error it says  WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: [storage/unknown] The server has terminated the upload session

Comment: Can you provide the GCP logs and the error that you are getting there?