# How to get the JSON from promise

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

**Code:**

```
fetch(`https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=++++++++++&tags=obama&format=json&extras=url_m&nojsoncallback=true`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers : { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
     }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.json())
  })
```

**Output:**

```
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
```

Comment: Add another then: `fetch(...).then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => ...)`

Comment: Why are you sending a `Content-type` header in a `GET` request? You don't send any content with `GET`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could await the response:

```
fetch(url, options).then(async (response) => {
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Yeah cool That's work simply I am looking the same thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Add another then:

```
fetch(...).then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => ...)
```

Note that `fetch` will only error on a network errors, if you want it to reject the Promise on e.g. a 500 response you'll have to check the status code and throw:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(resp => {
     // you'll need to supply the function that checks the status here
     if (http_response_ok(resp.status)) {
       return resp.json();
     } else {
       throw new Error(`Got back ${resp.status}`);
     }
  }).then(data => {
     // happy path
  }).catch(err => {
     // sad path
  });
```

Comment: Got from:  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani add a catch handler, see my updated answer.

Comment: Got:    console.log("sad path")

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842499/react-native-possible-unhandled-promise-rejection for information about that react-native warning

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani do `console.log(err);` you should see the actual error.

Comment: I got from err:  ReferenceError: http_response_ok is not defined

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani as I said in the comment in the code, you'll have to define it. An easy one would be something like `const http_response_ok = code => (code < 400) && (code >= 200);` but you can be as fine-grained as you want.