# Possible unhandled promise rejection, network error when using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

I'm trying to send JSON data using react-native, axios and Expo, but when I press "Send" on my application, I get this warning:

> Possible unhandled promise rejection, Error: Network Error

My API is correctly receiving the notification (JSON) when I try to send it via POSTman, but when I try to send it using axios, I get the above warning message, so maybe react is not sending the data correctly.

```
export default class NotificationsInput extends React.Component {

state = {
    token: '',
    title: '',
    body: ''
}

handleToken = event => {
    this.setState({ token: event.target.value })
}

handleTitle = event => {
    this.setState({ title: event.target.value })
}

handleBody = event => {
    this.setState({ body: event.target.value })
}

handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let notification = JSON.stringify({
        token: this.state.token,
        title: this.state.title,
        body: this.state.body
    })

    let headers = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

    }
    axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/send_push_message/`, notification, headers)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        .then(error => console.log(error));

}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput onChange={this.handleToken}
                style={{ height: 25, width: 200, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1 }}
            />
            <TextInput onChange={this.handleTitle}
                style={{ height: 40, width: 200, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1 }}
            />
            <TextInput onChange={this.handleBody}
                style={{ height: 40, width: 200, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1 }}
            />
            <Button onPress={this.handleSubmit} title="Send">Send</Button>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

**Edit** :

I added the catch() function, but the error now is only `Network Error` in the console.

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let notification = JSON.stringify({
        token: this.state.token,
        title: this.state.title,
        body: this.state.body
    })

    let headers = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

    }
    axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/send_push_message/`, notification, headers)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

}
```

Comment: what is the warning message you are getting

Comment: possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0): Error: Network Error

Comment: your error suggests you are not handling the promise rejection which is to add `.catch` as mentioned by other users also check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842499/react-native-possible-unhandled-promise-rejection

Comment: after adding the `.catch` block what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: only network error

Comment: and what is that ? mention the exact error !

Comment: i think that i'm not sending correctly or the backend is not accepting, the console only shows "Network error" and some errors in node-modules

Comment: so check with that or post another question on that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native: Possible unhandled promise rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842499/react-native-possible-unhandled-promise-rejection)

Answer (score 4):

I can see you have chained two, .then which is not correct. You need a catch block to catch network errors. Take a look below

```
  axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/send_push_message/`, notification, headers)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: @Rik i meant in his piece of code. he was trying to catch err in .then

Comment: i tried adding a catch, but this only make the error pop in my console

Comment: @BielBorba that is correct which means your call is getting rejected from backend. I think it looking for some data in payload which it is not finding and failing. https://medium.com/@dtinth/making-unhandled-promise-rejections-crash-the-node-js-process-ffc27cfcc9dd

Answer (score 1):

Use catch instead of then for error handling.

```
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: i tried, but i keep gettin the same error on the console

Comment: Is CORS enabled on the backend?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Changed:

```
return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/hello')
```

to:

```
return axios.get('http://10.0.0.2:3000/hello')
```

and it works. In Android emulator, the localhost refers its device.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404

Answer (score 0):

If you have cors enabled in your backend stack,

then try replacing `127.0.0.1` with `10.0.2.2`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check again your api_url.

It should include 'http' or 'https'