# React Native fetch() on Drupa 8 Backend returns TypeError: Network request failed - works fine as a Node Script

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to log in over a React Native Frontend with this code:

```
fetch(url,{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Accept" :  'application/json',
      'X-CSRF-Token' :this.state.token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(login),
  })
    .then(res => res)
    .then(res => {

        console.log(res);
    this.setState({uid:res.current_user.uid})
})
```

When I do this as a simple node script and execute, it works fine but not in React Native. It just throws:
`[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]`

Am I missing something in the React Native Environment?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was really simple and a bit embarassing, really.

I wanted to connect through React Native from an Android Emulator. I had to set the url from `http://localhost/drupalpath` to `http://10.0.3.2/drupalpath` to access the host machine of the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Add a catch to this code to get better info

```
.catch(function(error) {
console.log('found a problem with fetch ...: ' + error.message);
```

With respect to Drupal login from Js, you may want look at the “fancy login module for Drupal”

See : for more.

[React Native: Possible unhandled promise rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842499/react-native-possible-unhandled-promise-rejection)

Comment: Thank you for the tip! But i found the problem