# there is some error when i using url and parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

when i use this code in goole console it works like this

[image]

but when i use same code in react-native there is only data in _url like this

I want to get values ​​from searchParams.

[image]

this is my code

```
    const Kakao = ({navigation}) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        Linking.addEventListener('url', async ({url}) => {
          const urll =  new URL(
            'demo://app?accessToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6bnVsbCwicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJrYWthbyIsImlhdCI6MTYxODM5NDgwNX0.GfYs5rt0tjBrUmNvNIT6Bn_7TlJfY7zF9NxvkdqeTE0/',
          );

          console.log('urll.search', urll.search);

        });
        return () => Linking.removeEventListener('url');
      }, []);
```

how can i fix my code to get a urll.search data ???

Comment: Why did you make your eventListener async? There is no asynchronous code in there?

Comment: @derpirscher is becuase i should use the other logic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native: Possible unhandled promise rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842499/react-native-possible-unhandled-promise-rejection)